# Laravel - create a local copy of package with composer repositories feature

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, autoload

The previous company which worked on the project is using their own package for the admin panel.
I want to have total control over it.
I tried the following:

- I created a packages folder in the root of my Laravel app.
- I copied the package folder from the vendor into packages.
- I added it as a repository in my composer.json

  "repositories": [

  ```
       {
           "type": "path",
           "url": "./packages/provision/administration"
       }
   ],
   "require": {
       "php": ">=7.0.0",
       "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.3.0.9",
       "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
       "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
       "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
       "gentor/smart-ucf": "dev-master",
       "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
       "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
       "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
       "predis/predis": "^1.1",
       "provision/administration": "dev-master" // Changed from v5.5.x-dev to dev-master
   },`
  ```

Then I tried to run `composer update` and the following problem occured: `provision/administration dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.3.x-dev]`

These are the requirements from the provision/administration package:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6.4 || ^7.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*", // Not 5.3
    "provision/minifier": "dev-master",
    "provision/media-manager": "v5.5.x-dev",
    "provision/meta-tags": "dev-master",
    "provision/visual-builder": "dev-master",
    "provision/translation": "v5.5.x-dev",
    "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.3",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
    ...
```

The local package is an exact copt of the official one from the vendor folder. When it is in the vendor and I run composer update, this error does not occure.